# Iterating over two sets while updating two other sets in Haskell

Tags: haskell, nested-loops, set

I am trying to translate the following imperative code to a functional solution in Haskell.  I want to compare the members of set `s` with members of set `s'` and update sets `t` and `t'` based on the comparison.  Here is the imperative pseudocode:

```
-- s, s', t, t' are of type Data.Set a
-- foo x y returns a Just a or Nothing 
foo :: a -> a -> Just a

-- Initialize t and t' to s and s'
t = s
t = s'

foreach x in s
  foreach y in s'
      if (foo x y) == Just z
        insert z into t
        delete x from t
        delete y from t'

return (t, t')
```

The type of the Haskell function I am wishing for may be something like,

```
mergeSets :: S.Set -> S.Set -> (S.Set, S.Set)
mergeSets s s' = ...
```

where `S` is type `Data.Set` and the result of the function will be a pair with the new sets `t` and `t'` (or some other way to return both sets `t` and `t'`).

Comment: It would help to know what `foo` is supposed to do.'Returns a new element' is a bit unclear. Are you finding the set intersection, or union?

Comment: This is a fairly odd set of requirements. If you tell us more about what you're really trying to do (some context would be nice), we might be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that your pseudocode is incorrect, as the result of it will depend on the order of traversal of the two sets. To me it seems likely that you actually want to construct a cartesian product, process the pairs and then remove certain elements from the resulting sets.

Comment: Thank you for all the prompt responses.  The context is logic function minimization using the tabulation method in digital design.  Going into all the details would be difficult.  The context of the above:  I start with a Map of Sets keyed by integers.  The elements of the set are binary numbers.  The numbers are grouped by the number of ones in their binary rep.  E.g., 1000 would be in Set 1 and 1011 would be in Set 3.  The algo is to merge adjacent sets; merge Set 0 with Set 1 to create a new Sets 0 and 1, merge Set 1 with Set 2 to create a new Set 1 and 2 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
bar s s' =
  foldl (\ (t,t') (z,(x,y)) -> 
              ( delete x (insert z t) , delete y t' ))
    (s,s')
    [(z,(x,y)) | x <- toList s, y <- toList s', Just z <- [foo x y]]
```

The main question here is whether you intended for your insertions and deletions to interfere with the `foreach` mechanism. The above assumes that you did not.

If your sets are any large, you may need to add strictness, to avoid thunks blow-up:

```
bar s s' = foldl (\ (t,t') (z,(x,y)) ->
             let a=insert z t; b=delete x a; c=delete y t' 
             in a `seq` b `seq` c `seq` (b,c) )
    ....
```

Comment: I think avoiding interference was the purpose of initializing `t` and `t'` to `s` and `s'` then iterating over `s` and `s'`.

Comment: @luqui you're right! Then that qualification is unnecessary (was worded wrong, should've talked about OP's intent, whether they intended the interference, the updates-while-looping). Although, that copy `t=s` stuff would depend on the language's implementation, whether it performs deep copy or not.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of initializing `t` and `t'` was to avoid interference.  I am still getting used to folds, so I will need to stare at this for a little longer.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Neil folds are just about rolling along the list. Here, from the left, so the initial `(s,s')` goes on the left, and the list's element `(z,(x,y))` goes on the right - producing the result of same type as the argument on the left (so it goes, again on the left, into the next invocation of the combining function - picture it as `init+a+b+c+...` parenthesized to the left, `(...(((init+a)+b)+c)+...)`). You may have to add some strictness here, if your sets are of any substantial size.

Comment: @WillNess This works perfectly!  Thanks.  I am not sure if the sets I will work with will be large; but if they do, I may get back to you on what you mean by adding strictness.  I really enjoy the elegance of Haskell.  Just so that there is no confusion for future readers, the `foo` in `foo s s'` in the function definition is not the same function as the `foo` in `Just z <- [foo x y]` in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a collection data type like `Set` you're typically not going to write loops over the elements. That would be more appropriate for lists. So if your algorithm requires enumerating all the elementss in some nested way, convert the Set to [a list.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Set.html#v%3atoList)

So, I would try to avoid using your nested loop algo entirely on sets, and instead look for some declarative specification in terms of set operations: intersection, union, difference etc.

If that's not possible, a naive translation to lists is certainly possible:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

mergeSets :: Ord a => S.Set a -> S.Set a -> (S.Set a, S.Set a)
mergeSets s t = go1 (S.toList s) s t
    where
        go1 []     t t' = (t,t')
        go1 (x:xs) t t' = go1 xs u u'
            where
                (u, u') = go2 x (S.toList t) t t'

        go2 x []     t t'       = (t,t')
        go2 x (y:ys) t t'
            | Just z <- foo x y = go2 x ys (S.delete x (S.insert z t)) (S.delete y t')
            | otherwise         = go2 x ys t t'

-- for example
foo x y = if x == y then Just x else Nothing
```

The simple bit is modelling a nested loop. We could have used e.g. a list comprehension. However, your algo uses mutation of the output sets, so we need to pass that as an accumulating parameter.

To really get this nicely into Haskell though, we need to give up the element-by-element imperative style, and work in terms of the natural Set api. That will be your road to a nice solution.

Comment: I think this may work. I will give it a shot.  Thank you very much.

Comment: perhaps you meant `(u, u') = go2 x (S.toList t') t t'` ?